# Mainframe and frontend access

Tags: mainframe

So I understand mainframes process data in batches. With millions of transactions per second, how is the frontend getting the most up to date data if the next batch hasn't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a very simple view: The word 'mainframe' relates to a type of computer hardware architecture, which differs from the Desktop PC design. Mainframes are usually designed for use in large organizations and it also must have an operational system and applications designed accordingly to their purpose.
In the last decades the Desktop PC architecture evolution was astonishing, substituting  and confining even more the mainframes to very specific uses.

Your question is relevant. Indeed, online transactions must somehow be stored and computed in real time, and they are.
Many companies don't need a mainframe for this, nowadays it's usual to find a powerful desktop architecture computer running ERP applications capable of online processing and batch analytical processes.  Online transactions occur in real time retrieving and storing data in matter seconds.
The batch processes aims different purposes, running usually on a overnight basis in order to produce Analytical data,for business support, reports, data consolidation, etc.  If needed, of course mainframes also could do the same.

Comment: Thank you. So to be clear, it's not common for banks and other financial companies yo do rtp on mainframes?

Comment: If you're talking about "thin clients", and RDP remote access, then generally they'll go with a "server farm" of multiple servers that are desktop architecture but in a data center somewhere. So many programs are written for the desktop architecture now that it makes a lot more sense to run them on that architecture directly. But large financial institutions may also have a mainframe for large batch processing of data sets generated by those RDP farms.

Comment: Mainframes are quite capable of interactive operations and, with NUMA and virtualization, PCs are starting to look and behave more like mainframes. The nomenclature is increasingly becoming a marketing differentiator rather than a technical one.

Comment: Yes, sure @MattMorrow,  big companies do have mainframes. I meant that desktop architecture is expanding and taking place where only mainframes used to be.